# Offline registration/activation of visual studio 2013 express?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've visual studio 2013 express installed on an old computer without network connection. Now after 30 days, it requires me to sign in to online account to update the license, or else I won't able to continue to use it. Anyone knows how to update the license offline?

Comment: Relevant [SU question](http://superuser.com/q/730511/47225).